# Joomla 3 category RSS feed reveals Registered-only article

Tags: joomla, rss, acl

I am building a Joomla 3 website where some articles in a category are intended to be viewed only by registered users, while other articles in the same category are intended to be public.

In testing an article with the "Registered" access level, I find that article's content is revealed in the public Atom/RSS feeds for the category. My expectation is that the article content should not be there.

Here is my test:

http://incyanity.net/index.php/hote

This page is a Category List. The "Test" article correctly displays "Register to read more...". Additionally, in the menu at the top of the page, the drop-down list for this category correctly displays the Test link with a lock icon beside it. The menu item is set to public so visitors can see where the protected content is. Clicking on the menu item takes the user to an error page. Great! This is all desirable behavior.
Edit: I *had* the menu item set to public and it was working the way I described above, but when I tested just now it seems the behavior has changed again to allow guests to see the whole article. This now forces me to hide the menu item too which is not what I want to do. :( The whole article is still in the Atom/RSS feed though!

http://incyanity.net/index.php/hote?format=feed&type=atom

Both this feed and the RSS version shows the entirety of the body of the "Test" article. Why is this happening? I do want feeds available for people to follow *public* content published to this category, but anything that requires registration should not be included (or, ideally, the feed should only contain an entry that says something like "[Article Title] has been published. Log in at the website to view").

Since the menu item is set to public, I did try setting it to "Registered" on the off chance that had anything to do with this but the entire "Test" article still displayed in the Atom and RSS feeds.

I've tried asking for help on the official Joomla forum plus various searches on Google for solutions to this and unless my Google-fu is weak I just can't seem to find any answers. I feel like the behavior I'm looking for should be natively supported by Joomla given the integrated user access levels and ideally I want to solve this without turning to a third party plugin.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To review the configuration, you set:

- Article manager options: Show unauthorized links "test"
- Article options: View access level: registered;

The first option ensures that you get the links to the articles which have the "access level=registered", and that they show in blogs and category lists.

The second, sets the article's access level as Registered.

This is fine. But in order for Joomla to be able to show the articles in blogs, the introText of the article needs to be visible to all as well.  Here comes the trick.

Just add a "Read more" tag (with the button at the bottom of the editor) in the article; the text after the tag will be hidden. The first part of the article needs to be visible to all, otherwise neither Joomla (nor search engines) would be able to show it.

So just add the read more tag... it's that easy. If you don't want any text showing you can start the article with it, but it's against your interest.

Comment: I believe the problem he's having (and which I can see) is that the RSS feed is showing the entire article.

Comment: I just re-tested and I could only see the introtext both in the website and in the rss feed, hence I guess he's just missing the readmore tag.  He _might_ have a template override of the rss feed which is querying the database directly to show the full text, but that's fairly unlikely.

Comment: Yes, unauthorized links are set to be visible, and the article view option is set to be registered. The articles that I want to be visible only to registered users do not have any "intro" text that should be public--that would be counterproductive, especially as there is no blog for that category. It seems pretty silly to me that the "Read More" link should be a solution here--but I will try it.

Comment: readmore works in a strange way: upon saving, Joomla will store the portion of the text before the readmore in the introtext column, and the rest in the fulltext; the latter is the one that will be shown to registered users; in the introtext you may put a statement and a link to your registration page; and use the article configuration to prevent showing the introtext in the full article. This should give you enough flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I haven't tested this yet... Got a bit distracted with RL stuff. But if it works out the way I need I'll return to update.

Comment: It works! I can use 'You must be logged in to view this article.' as the intro text on these pages and that will work out. The Atom/RSS feed updated properly to reflect this too. I'm happy! Thanks for your help!